# How to search TextField for regular expression in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am submitting a form in Django and I wrote a clean function, that attempts to go through the TextField and looks to see if any of the  words in that field match words formatted like this --> #tweet, #people, and so on, but I just can not seem to get it working(the form saves fine btw), my knowledge of regular expression is around zero, and yes I know I could have used a model form here but I like experimenting because I am new to Django.

forms.py

```
    class TweetForm(forms.Form):
       tweets = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), initial='Write your tweets here')

      class Meta:
        fields=('tweets',)




      def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        regular = re.compile('\b#\w\w+')
        clean_tweets = data['tweets']
        for lines in clean_tweets:
          words = regular.findall(lines)
          for hashtags in words:
             print hashtags #want to print them in the terminal


      def __init__(self, userprofile, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TweetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.userprofile = userprofile


      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data=self.cleaned_data
        obj = Tweet(tweets=data['tweets'], userprofile=self.userprofile, date=timezone.now(), )
        obj.save()
```

Comment: What is with all the names? `bird`, `hello`, `tony`?...

Comment: I name thing sort of randomly its a bad habit.

Comment: Seeing your question & code, I think this question is too broad to be answered here. Also, while what you want is not terribly complicated, IMHO it's above your level right now. I suggest you start with something simpler and grok it as best as possible (and you can ask more specific questions here of course). Oh and start using meaningful variables! Even you yourself won't know what they mean when you re-visit your code sometime later. Sorry I hope I didn't come off as condescending :) Keep on learning mate!

Comment: Alright man I agree with you i was being to ambitious for where i am at right now, thanks for knocking me down so i can focus on learning more immediate needs!

Comment: edited my question with more knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out and this is how you could do it, I turned the data in to a list and then just ran a for loop with an enumerator.

forms.py

```
    def clean(self):
      data = self.cleaned_data
      regex = re.compile("\B#\w\w+")
      cleaned_tweets = data['tweets']
      split_tweets = cleaned_tweets.split()
      for i, x in enumerate(split_tweets):
         if re.search(regex, x):
             print i, x
```